# Jquery - how to format data for Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When calling `alert()`on variable `UserData`, I get the following output:

> TestUser, mail@example.com, 2

The variable `UserData` is of type Object according to `alert(typeof UserData)`. I'm trying to pass it to a jQuery Ajax call, but on the server side my POST data is empty.

If I do `JSON.stringify(UserData)`, it becomes:

```
["TestUser","mail@example.com","2"]
```

Still not getting any POST data though.

Here's the Ajax call:

```
request = $.ajax({
 url: "edit_user.php",
 type: "post",
 data: UserData,
 dataType: "json"
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: depends on what the receiving end is expecting. remember that ajax is really just an http call. if edit_user.php is expecting a normal html form submission, then formatting as json is pointless. you'd want to form.serialize() instead.

Comment: @MarcB It's not normal html form submission. The data is extracted from table cells `<td>` within a specific table line `<tr>`. I'm not sure how to properly format `UserData`. Maybe I need to convert `UserData` to an associative array with indexes mapped to POST indexes.

Comment: doesn't matter. if the script is expecting data in the format that a normal form submission would send, then you have send your data in that format. doesn't matter if you're slicing/dicing the form, the server is expecting key:value pairs to populate $_POST with, and your json string doesn't satisfy that. if you'd done `data: {json:UserData}`, then you'd have gotten `$_POST['json']` containing your json string.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks. Now the POST data is coming through by using `{json:UserData}`. This way there's no need to format `UserData` as a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

try to create a oject that looks like this and pass it to the data property of the ajax call `{user:"TestUser",email:"mail@example.com",id:"2"}` or as Mark suggested use  `serialize()`to crate this object

Comment: this must help you @Sam32

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your UserData is array, not object, and it does not have proper keys (field names). You didn't mention, how UserData is formed, where it comes from. Check there, make sure it looks like `{user:"TestUser",email:"mail@example.com",id:"2"}` and not like `["TestUser","mail@example.com","2"]` when you stringify it. then you can simply pass it via ajax data field.

Answer (score 0):

We can't see where UserData comes from or how it's formed but extract your data from your object and try this

```
var dynamicData = [];
dynamicData.push({name: 'name', value: 'TestUser'});
dynamicData.push({name: 'email', value: 'mail@example.com'});
```

Replace the value (TestUser, mail@example.com) with the extracted data from UserData. Maybe

```
dynamicData.push({name: 'name', value: UserData[0]});
```